# Issue with allocating object and releasing ios

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak with below code.
Where self.firstURLConn is @property(nonatomic, retain).

```
NSMutableURLRequest* req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:urlcachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0f];

self.firstURLConn = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self] autorelease];

[req release];//memory leak here and with self.firstURLConn
```

Why memory is leaking here

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever run Product > Analyze yet? If you did please show us the memory leaking issue log.

They will not only tell the line of your code that have memory leak issue but show the step of your code that cause the problem.

I suggest you to use Instrument tool with leaking tool. It will show the in-depth information about your code problem.

**EDIT:** req variable miss autorelease. because of `req` has been retain 2 time. change the code like this

```
NSMutableURLRequest* req = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:urlcachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0f] autorelease];

self.firstURLConn = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self] autorelease];

[req release];//memory leak here and with self.firstURLConn
```

Because of your `firstURLConn` has declared in retain properties. So,the dealloc method, you should set `nil` to this properties

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.firstURLConn = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: In my question i mentioned where memory is leaking.

Comment: Let me analysis from your full code. Please show your problem class .h and .m code.

Answer (score 0):

firstURLConn will retain your req, req will be only deallocated when firstURLConn will  release req.

Answer (score 0):

Since the delegate method returns asynchronously (sometime in the future) you must release the NSURLConnection inside of the delegate method. Remove the autorelease and add a release in the completed and failed delegate methods.